# Given a mapping for $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3 , A,$ find new basis for $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$ such that the mapping is now diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

Given a mapping for $\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R^3$ , $A,$ find new basis for $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$ such that the mapping is now diagonal. Note that $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$ currently use the standard basis.

I was thinking of using singular value decomposition. In this case would the new basis for $\mathbb R^2$ be the columns of $V$ and $\mathbb R^3$ be the columns of $U$ for $A = US$($V$ transpose)

Comment: If the mapping is a rotation of the $xy$-plane, how can you find eigenvectors on the plane?

Comment: You can simply row-reduce and then column-reduce. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2728785/265466.